# Combining get query with insert query

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I feel there is no shortcut to this but still wanted to check.

Say i have an collection which looks like this

```
[{
userName: "Mr. A"
income: 100   
expense: null
finalBalance: 200
timestamp: Date.now()
}]
```

*if we have income amount, expense will be null and vice versa
final balance = (sum of income) - (sum of expense)
Stack: mongodB+node.js

Basically need to know the shortest and best way possible to insert new objects in the collections which involves calculating new "finalBalance" everytime.

Curretly what i do is every time i have to insert a new transaction like shown on the top.
I fetch the last transction for that user using "timestamp" and "userName", and then add or substract the income or expense amount from it and
create the new object and insert.

For example:

last transaction of user:

```
{
userName: "Mr. A"
income: 100   
expense: null
finalBalance: 200
timestamp: Date.now()
}
```

Need to insert new transaction for user with details

```
({userName: "Mr. A", expense: 10})
```

step 1:(get from DB) Fetch the last transaction for user from DB to get the last "finalBalance".

step 2: substract the "expense" amount from "finalBalance" to get new "finalBalance" which will be (200 - 10 = 190)

step 3:(insert in DB) Make insert

```
{
userName: "Mr. A"
income: null   
expense: 10
finalBalance: 190
timestamp: Date.now()
}
```

Is there a way in which we can calculate the new "finalBalance" and insert the new object with one DB call?

It would be great if the solution is with mongo.js

Answer (score 0):

You can't use your own document values to update it. So, to perform this kind of operations, you will have to `find` it and iterate over it with `forEach`. Then, it will give you your document(s) and you will be able to modify them and `save` them :

```
var yourObj = {userName: "Mr. A", expense: 10};
db.collection.find({yourObj.userName}).forEach(doc =>  {
  doc.finalBalance = doc.finalBalance - yourObj.expense;
  doc.timestamp: Date.now();

  db.events.save(doc);
})
```

Try it and tell me if it works as expected,

Hope it helps,
Best regards

Comment: Hi Thanks for the suggestion i will try this out. But this will not work my case. As i need a single query for the complete thing, not mentioned in the question but i will be doing insert many using that query, as i have an array or such transactions to be inserted. But yeah if that kind of query cant be written i can use your suggestion.